# Want to play video but there´s only sound, no visible content

Tags: iphone, xcode

i have a tabbar based application with 2 tabs. One to show images and the other to show videos. If i click on the video tab, different thumbnails are showing up. If i click on one of these images, i would like to push that videoviewController to play a video in another navigation view - if i turn the iphone around, it will play fullscreen. So, actually its the same functionality like the original "photo"- app.

What i´ve got so far is a scrollview with different buttons where i added a backgroundimage. By clicking on one of these buttons, i´ve added the button-functionality:

```
            [myButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(buttonDown: ) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And here´s my "buttonDown"-method:

```
-(void) buttonDown:(NSString*) sender {
moviePlayer = [[MoviePlayer alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

NSLog(@"MoviePlayer:  %@", moviePlayer);
[self.navigationController pushViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES];

[moviePlayer release];}
```

Here´s my "MoviePlayer.m"-file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

UIView* imageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100 )];
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];

NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testmovie" ofType:@"mp4"];
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
//player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

[player play];    
[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

```
- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];    
[player autorelease];
```

}

So the navigation works great - by clicking on a button, the view is pushed (and i get my green test-uiview) and the sound of that video file is been playing - but no video is visible, only that sound.

I´ve no idea - if i test that code in a new viewbased-project-template it works great. So i think there some problems with the views.

Any ideas on that?
Would be great. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

[player setFullscreen:YES]; 
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];

I believe that should resolve your woes! Please vote for answer if it assists!